# SQL Insert from powershell failing with quotation mark

Tags: sql, powershell

Hi firstly thanks for looking at this post. I am new to this so apologize if i get the format wrong.

i am inserting audit specification data from SQL audit into a SQL table - the problem is when i run the statement from PS it fails when the SQL output comes across a ' for example

```
CREATE LOGIN [TEST] WITH PASSWORD=N'******', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

the '******' fails due to the quote.

the column it fails on is `$row.statement`

here is my statement:

```
# POWERSHELL SCRIPT TO PULL yesterday's AUDIT DATA FROM SELECTED SQL SERVERS 

(Read from DBA..SQLAuditTargets)
#Proof of concept Auto Pull data


#Load SMO
#[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null;
#Load SQL Module

#Import-Module SqlPs | Out-Null
#Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 | Out-Null
#Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100 | Out-Null

# Set target Server/DB to write data to.
$TargetServerInstance=''
$TargetServerDB='DBA'

#Set CMS server source 
$CMSSERVER='SQL1'


function Write-DataTable
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ServerInstance,
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Database,
    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$TableName,
    [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$true)] $Data,
    [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Username,
    [Parameter(Position=5, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Password,
    [Parameter(Position=6, Mandatory=$false)] [Int32]$BatchSize=50000,
    [Parameter(Position=7, Mandatory=$false)] [Int32]$QueryTimeout=0,
    [Parameter(Position=8, Mandatory=$false)] [Int32]$ConnectionTimeout=15
    )

    $conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection

    if ($Username)
    { $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Trusted_Connection=False;Connect Timeout={4}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$Username,$Password,$ConnectionTimeout }
    else
    { $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$ConnectionTimeout }

    $conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString

    try
    {
        $conn.Open()
        $bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $connectionString
        $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $tableName
        $bulkCopy.BatchSize = $BatchSize
        $bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = $QueryTimeOut
        $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($Data)
        $conn.Close()
    }
    catch
    {
        $ex = $_.Exception
        Write-Error "$ex.Message"
        continue
    }

} #Write-DataTable


function Out-DataTable
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] [PSObject[]]$InputObject)

    Begin
    {
        $dt = new-object Data.datatable  
        $First = $true 
    }
    Process
    {
        foreach ($object in $InputObject)
        {
            $DR = $DT.NewRow()  
            foreach($property in $object.PsObject.get_properties())
            {  
                if ($first)
                {  
                    $Col =  new-object Data.DataColumn  
                    $Col.ColumnName = $property.Name.ToString()  
                    $DT.Columns.Add($Col)
                }  
                if ($property.IsArray)
                { $DR.Item($property.Name) =$property.value | ConvertTo-XML -AS String -NoTypeInformation -Depth 1 }  
                else { $DR.Item($property.Name) = $property.value }  
            }  
            $DT.Rows.Add($DR)  
            $First = $false
        }
    } 

    End
    {
        Write-Output @(,($dt))
    }

} #Out-DataTable


###### Get Dynamic list of servers names to loop through.
#Change LIKE clause to signify Prod/dev etc.


$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server="+$CMSServer+";Database=master;Integrated Security=True"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT SQLName FROM DBA..SQLAuditTargets  "
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 15
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()


    #Initialize Array to hold new database objects
$iDatabases = @()
$servers = $DataSet.Tables[0] | % {([string]$_.SQLName).Trim()}
    #Loop over each SQLName provided (SQLName is column in source table)

foreach ($instance in $servers)

{
    try
   {
        "Connecting to $instance" | Write-Host -ForegroundColor green

############################
$DbQuery="DECLARE @auditfile varchar(200) SET @auditfile=(select log_file_path +LEFT(log_file_name, CHARINDEX('_',log_file_name))+'*.sqlaudit' from sys.server_file_audits where log_file_name LIKE '%DBA-SQL-Audit%')

                          SELECT        

                          af.event_time, aa.class_desc, af.action_id, af.session_id, af.server_instance_name, af.database_name, af.server_principal_name, af.schema_name, af.object_name, af.statement, aa.containing_group_name, aa.covering_action_name

                          FROM            sys.fn_get_audit_file(@auditfile, NULL, NULL) AS af INNER JOIN
                                                    sys.dm_audit_actions AS aa ON af.action_id = aa.action_id INNER JOIN
                                                    sys.dm_audit_class_type_map AS ctm ON aa.class_desc = ctm.securable_class_desc
                          WHERE        (af.statement <> '')

                                                     AND (aa.class_desc <> 'SERVER') 

                                                    AND (af.database_name <> 'master') 
                          AND (ctm.class_type_desc = 'DATABASE') 
                          AND (af.action_id IN ('AL', 'DR', 'CR', 'SVPD', 'SVSD', 'SVSR')) 
                          AND (af.object_name NOT IN ('dbo', '', 'telemetry_xevents'))


                          AND af.Event_Time > '2018-02-27 00:00:28.0000000' and af.Event_Time < '2018-02-28 08:42:28.0000000'

                           GROUP BY 

                          af.event_time, aa.class_desc, af.action_id, af.session_id, af.server_instance_name, af.database_name, af.server_principal_name, af.schema_name, af.object_name, af.statement, aa.containing_group_name, aa.covering_action_name

                          UNION

                          SELECT   

                          af.event_time, aa.class_desc, af.action_id, af.session_id, af.server_instance_name, af.database_name, af.server_principal_name, af.schema_name , af.object_name, af.statement, aa.containing_group_name, aa.covering_action_name

                          FROM            sys.fn_get_audit_file(@auditfile, NULL, NULL) AS af INNER JOIN
                                                   sys.dm_audit_actions AS aa ON af.action_id = aa.action_id INNER JOIN
                                                   sys.dm_audit_class_type_map AS ctm ON aa.class_desc = ctm.securable_class_desc
                          WHERE        (af.statement <> '') 

                          AND (aa.class_desc <> 'DATABASE') 
                          AND (ctm.class_type_desc = 'SERVER AUDIT') 
                          AND (af.database_name = 'master') 
                          AND (af.object_name NOT IN ('dbo', '', 'telemetry_xevents'))

                          AND af.Event_Time > '2018-02-26 06:10:01.3531160'

                          GROUP BY 

                          af.event_time, aa.class_desc, af.action_id, af.session_id, af.server_instance_name, af.database_name, af.server_principal_name, af.schema_name, af.object_name, af.statement, aa.containing_group_name, aa.covering_action_name"
write-output $row
#Connect
#$AuditOutput=invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $instance  -Query $DbQuery  -Querytimeout 30
$AuditOutput=invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $instance -Database 'Master' -Query $DbQuery  -Querytimeout 30
############################


######################################################################
# Write Output to Target SQL Server table (SQL1, DBA database)
######################################################################
#Connect to the SQL server and the Database

    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source="+$TargetServerInstance+"; Initial Catalog="+$TargetServerDB+"; Integrated Security=SSPI")
# Open DB Connection
    $conn.Open()


##################################
#DATABASES DETAILS INSERT
##################################
#Loop through each row   
foreach ($row in $AuditOutput)
    {
#Create SQL Insert Statement with Audit values
    $db_insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[SQLAuditStaging]
           ([event_time]
           ,[class_desc]
           ,[action_id]
           ,[session_id]
           ,[server_instance_name]
           ,[database_name]
           ,[server_principal_name]
           ,[schema_name]
           ,[object_name]
           ,[statement]
           ,[containing_group_name]
           ,[covering_action_name])

           VALUES ('$($row.event_time)','$($row.class_desc)','$($row.action_id)','$($row.session_id)','$($row.server_instance_name)','$($row.database_name)','$($row.server_principal_name)','$($row.schema_name)','$($row.object_name)','$($row.statement)','$($row.containing_group_name)', '$($row.covering_action_name)')" 
#    ## Create your command (Services)
    $cmddb = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmddb.CommandText = $db_insert_stmt
#     ## Invoke the Insert statement
        $cmddb.ExecuteNonQuery()
   } 


#Log Details of collection success
# Log collection success to table here

## Close DB Connection
     $conn.Close()


   }
     catch
    {
       "Error on collections with $instance." | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red
  #Error log info collection here     
    }

    }
```

Thanks In advance....

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a parameterized query.  One because your code is throwing errors due to quote escaping, and two because string concatenation is vulnerable to SQL injection. They're not that difficult.

Try something like this:

```
##################################
#DATABASES DETAILS INSERT
##################################
#Create SQL Insert Statement

$db_insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[SQLAuditStaging] ([event_time], [class_desc], [action_id], [session_id], [server_instance_name], [database_name], [server_principal_name], [schema_name], [object_name], [statement], [containing_group_name], [covering_action_name])
VALUES (@event_time,
@class_desc,
@action_id,
@session_id,
@server_instance_name,
@database_name,
@server_principal_name,
@schema_name,
@object_name,
@statement,
@containing_group_name,
@covering_action_name)" 

#Loop through each row   
foreach ($row in $AuditOutput) {
    $cmddb = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmddb.CommandText = $db_insert_stmt

    # Assign parameter values
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@event_time'           ,[System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime2).Value = $row.event_time
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@class_desc'           ,[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar).Value  = $row.class_desc
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@action_id'            ,[System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).Value       = $row.action_id
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@session_id'           ,[System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).Value       = $row.session_id
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@server_instance_name' ,[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar).Value  = $row.server_instance_name
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@database_name'        ,[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar).Value  = $row.database_name
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@server_principal_name',[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar).Value  = $row.server_principal_name
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@schema_name'          ,[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar).Value  = $row.schema_name
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@object_name'          ,[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar).Value  = $row.object_name
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@statement'            ,[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar).Value  = $row.statement
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@containing_group_name',[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar).Value  = $row.containing_group_name
    $cmddb.Parameters.Add('@covering_action_name' ,[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar).Value  = $row.covering_action_name

    $cmddb.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

Note that the data types used in the parameter should match the data types of `[dbo].[SQLAuditStaging]`.  The values of the columns in `$row` should also be the relevant data type.  I've made a guess above.  Use [this chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) to determine how the data types are intended to match up.